# Turning indexed array to associative array that still works with a CSV file. -PHP

Tags: php, arrays, csv, associative

I can't seem to find an answer. Is there an easy way to change my array in the code, to an associative array?

NOTE:
-All the variables being assigned are declared already
-It basically creates an array from a csv file called staff data and loops through to find the next empty line then adds that row with data, then re-saves back into the csv file. 
My problem is that I cannot figure out in the slightest how to change this array to an associative array that will still work with my code.. Any direction would be greatly appreciated. I hope my problem is clear.

```
// Grabs the csv file (and its existing data)  and makes it into an array so the new data can be added to it.
$StaffDetails = array();
$lines = file('data/StaffData.csv', FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES);
foreach ($lines as $key => $value)
{
    $StaffDetails[$key] = str_getcsv($value);
}

//This is a for loop that checks when there is an avaliable line to put the data into. It loops over the lines, until there is an empty spot for the new data //to go into.
//It will not run it if the full name is empty.

for ($i=0; $i<200; $i++) {
    if(empty($StaffDetails[$i][0]) == false){ //If its full

    }else if (empty($StaffDetails[$i][0]) == true){ //If it is empty 



        //This prints the details of this staff to that line in the data file. $i is the avaliable line found above.        
        $StaffDetails[$i][0] = $UserFullName;
        $StaffDetails[$i][1] = $UserPhoneNumber;
        $StaffDetails[$i][2] = $Gender;
        $StaffDetails[$i][3] = $Birthday;
        $StaffDetails[$i][4] = $TypeOfWork;
        $StaffDetails[$i][5] = $StartingDate;
        $StaffDetails[$i][6] = $AnnualLeaveLeft;
        $StaffDetails[$i][7] = $SickLeaveLeft;
        $StaffDetails[$i][8] = $ID;
        $StaffDetails[$i][9] = $NumberOfWorkDaysAWeek;
        $StaffDetails[$i][10] = $Monday;
        $StaffDetails[$i][11] = $Tuesday;
        $StaffDetails[$i][12] = $Wednesday;
        $StaffDetails[$i][13] = $Thursday;
        $StaffDetails[$i][14] = $Friday;
        $StaffDetails[$i][15] = $Saturday;
        $StaffDetails[$i][16] = $Sunday;
        $StaffDetails[$i][17] = $UserUsername;
        $StaffDetails[$i][18] = $UserPassword;
        $StaffDetails[$i][19] = $Em1FullName;
        $StaffDetails[$i][20] = $Em1PhoneNumber;
        $StaffDetails[$i][21] = $Em2FullName;
        $StaffDetails[$i][22] = $Em2PhoneNumber;

    $i =201;


    }


    //Below saves the previous data and new changes to the csv file

//This opens the csv file as a write file
$MyCsvFile = fopen('data/StaffData.csv', 'w');


//This takes the array that has had data ddded to it and adds it to the file
foreach ($StaffDetails as $fields) {
    fputcsv($MyCsvFile, $fields);
}

//This closes the file
fclose($MyCsvFile);
}
```

Comment: "An array in PHP is actually an ordered map. A map is a type that associates *values* to *keys*." - [PHP: Arrays - Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php) ... "In computer science, an associative array is an abstract data type composed of a collection of (key, value) pairs." - [Associative Array - Wikipedia](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwj7jem-j_TNAhUEeSYKHV9RC9MQFgggMAE&url=https%3A%2F%2Fen.wikipedia.org%2Fwiki%2FAssociative_array&usg=AFQjCNFUkZALJxrtpEpcf5_ojjUiUe1NyA&sig2=CwJRRDol2v_9MxCTfW3PMQ)

Comment: So your indexed array *is* an associative array, in PHP. Perhaps I don't understand the question.

Comment: No its an indexed array, but I want to turn it into an associative array. Maybe I dont quite understand how an associative works in comparison to an indexed array..

Comment: That definition helps me understand it a bit more Jonny, -thanks! So is there a way to associate the values to other values and not keys? Or would all my code have to change? I hope that makes sense.

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what you're asking, which isn't a bad thing, it's sometimes hard to fully explain data structures. You should read up on arrays in PHP though, to figure out if it's the right data structure for your use case. [PHP: Arrays](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php)

Comment: Yeah that sounds like a good idea- I will do some reading and YouTubeing. Thanks for your time though. :-)

Comment: No problem at all, sorry I couldn't be of more help. Don't forget to check back on this question in case another user knows what you're asking.

Comment: Will do! No worries, I think I may be onto something,  I might edit my question later.